# Service endpoints chaining with Angular

Tags: angular, httpresponse, chaining

I have the following DataService, which should call the following APIs in a chain, so I am able to pass the response from the previous one to the next one. This is how I started so far, however I am getting the following error  when I try to access one of the properties of the response object:

Why does that happen, since when I console.log response, it has the following structure:

```
{
  "data": "",
  "id": ""
}
```

> Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Object'.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Person } from './entities/person';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import { mergeMap } from '../../node_modules/rxjs/operator/mergeMap';
import { Observable } from '../../node_modules/rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  results: Person[];
  apiUrl1: string = 'http://localhost:3000/person/';
  apiUrl2: string = 'http://localhost:3000/facility';
  apiUrl3: string = 'http://localhost:3000/exposure';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  createPerson(person: Person): Observable<any> {
    return (this.http.post(this.apiUrl1, person)
    .map(response => this.http.post(this.apiUrl2, response.data)));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Typescript strictly checks for the data property in your response, just change the response type as any,

```
.map((response : any) => this.http.post(this.apiUrl2, response.data)));
```

Comment: thank's that is fixed, however is not posting the data to the second api.

Comment: you need to check that on the network tab and debug it. mark if that helped

Comment: @CodeWorm You may want to try using `flatMap` instead of `map`.

Answer (score 0):

```
createPerson(person: Person): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(this.apiUrl1, person)
    .subscribe(response => {
        // do whatever you wanna do :
        this.http.post(this.apiUrl2, response.data)
        .subscribe(response2 => {
            // continue like this
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: `Observables` don't have a `then` function.